# count number of rows for a timestamp

Tags: python, machine-learning, timestamp, time-series

I am working on the dataset

https://pastebin.com/PEFUspiU

I have to group it and count how many requests are there for a particular period of time and then it will be easy to draw me a chart ***time vs the number of requests.***

for an example

```
**timestamp - number of request**

21-06-2016 09:00:00 - 2

21-06-2016 10:00:00 - 1

21-06-2016 11:00:00 - 5
```

how can I get this count?

*Thanks*

*P.S I tried use `data['timestamp'].value_counts()` but got errors:*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 6

dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
data = pd.read_csv('/home/amfirnas/Desktop/localhost_access_log.2016-06-21.csv',
                   parse_dates=['timestamp'], index_col='timestamp',date_parser=dateparse)

print data.head(25)

# print data['time'].value_counts()

# print data.groupby(['time']).groups.keys()

ts = data['timestamp'].value_counts()

# plt.plot(ts)
# plt.show()
```

Comment: Is your timestamp data coming in the list in data["timestamp"]?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count them for each hour, instead of value_count() you can group them and then count, for that, make sure that your timestamp is pandas datetime:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq="1H")).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading File:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('/home/local/sayali/Downloads/dataset-server_logs.csv')

[In]:df

              host            timestamp  status   byte
0  192.168.102.100  21-06-2016 09:54:44     200  17811
1  192.168.102.100  21-06-2016 09:54:44     200  21630
2  192.168.100.160  21-06-2016 10:08:08     404   1098
3  192.168.100.160  21-06-2016 11:20:44     200  17811
4  192.168.100.160  21-06-2016 11:20:44     200  21630
5  192.168.102.100  21-06-2016 11:54:44     200  17811
6  192.168.102.100  21-06-2016 11:54:44     200  21630
7  192.168.102.100  21-06-2016 11:54:44     200  21630

ts = pd.DataFrame(df['timestamp'].value_counts()))

ts
Out[15]: 
                     timestamp
2016-06-21 11:54:44          3
2016-06-21 09:54:44          2
2016-06-21 11:20:44          2
2016-06-21 10:08:08          1

#Convert index to datetime format using pd.to_datetime()
ts.index = pd.to_datetime(ts.index)

# PLOT
plt.title('Number of Requests based on timestamp') 
plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
plt.ylabel('Total number of Requests') 
#Change xticks orientation to vertical 
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')        
plt.plot(ts)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. and If I do ts = data['timestamp'].value_counts() plt.plot(ts) plt.show() I got empty graph

Comment: please check edited answer. Hope this helps :) Do not forget to convert timestamp to datetime format this is why you are not able to plot it.