# Col lost after convert it from DataFram to List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following problem... I want to group (period of 5h) and count timestamps. For that i found this Question/Solution:
[count number of rows for a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897394/count-number-of-rows-for-a-timestamp)
Now i want to convert it to an list, but only the counts are in the list, after i convert it. The timestamps were lost.

my code:

```
d = {"count": timestamps}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['count'])
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq="5H")).count()
print(df)

data = df.values.tolist()
print(data)
```

out:

```
                           count
timestamp                       
2020-11-03 10:00:00+00:00     10
2020-11-03 15:00:00+00:00      0
2020-11-03 20:00:00+00:00      0
2020-11-04 01:00:00+00:00      1
2020-11-04 06:00:00+00:00     19
2020-11-04 11:00:00+00:00     20
[[10], [0], [0], [1], [19], [20]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.values removes the index as you convert it into a numpy array.

Depending on how you want the order of the list you can do:

```
data =  df.index.tolist() + df.values.tolist()
```

which will list all of the index's and then all of the counts.

Or you can do:

```
data = [[df.index.tolist()[x], df.values.tolist()[x]] for x in range(len(df.values))]
```

to make a list of [ind, count] pairs.